Is there a good way to post a question on quant.stackexchange and stats.stackexchange simultaneously?
I have posted a question here on quant.stackexchange. There are some votes already but no comment and no answer. I can imagine that the question is interesting for the stats people too. Is there a way to duplicate the question that is "ok" concerning the standards? Thanks!

I assume you're talking about this one. If nobody answers it by tomorrow, then you can repost on Cross Validated and link back to this one with a statement that nobody has been able to answer it yet.

Correct, thanks for your opinion.
